# Calling function with onkeyup or with key event

Tags: javascript

I want to call a function **only** when the ENTER key is pressed (or released) in an `input` field. My old code worked but had the problem that it called the function on **every** keyup, not just the ENTER key:

Old HTML:

```
<input class="halter"  type="text" onkeyup="checkLoesung(id);">
```

JS:

```
function checkLoesung(id){do stuff}
```

Now I tried to change it so that only the ENTER key triggers the function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('halter').onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){
        checkLoesung(id){do stuff}
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Shouldn't this work if I remove the `onkeyup="checkLoesung(id);"` from my input element? Is the problem here connected to the `id` that I am trying to pass to the function?

EDIT: removed typo
EDIT 2: Full code:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<div id="digger_cont">
<p id="ueberschrift_koth">King of the Hill</p>
<div id="fragen_halter">
<input id="ha_1" class="halter" placeholder="안녕하세요"  type="text" ><br/>
<input id="ha_2" class="halter" placeholder="얼굴" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_3" class="halter" placeholder="유방" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_4" class="halter" placeholder="물" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_5" class="halter" placeholder="병" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_6" class="halter" placeholder="책상" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_7" class="halter" placeholder="노래" type="text" >
</div>
<div id="score_halter">
<p>Punkte: <span id="score_not" style="display:none"></span></p>
<p id="melder"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var l_count = 0; // Counter init, 0!
var last_sol = 7;  // ECHTE Anzahl an Luecken

document.getElementsByClassName('halter')[0].onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){

        checkLoesung(id);
      return false;
    }
  }


function checkLoesung(id){
    if(l_count != last_sol) {

        var e_dies = document.getElementById(id).id;

        var LoesungArray = [
            "Hallo",
            "gesicht",
            "brust",
            "wasser",
            "flasche",
            "tisch",
            "lied"
            ];

        var score_not = document.getElementById('score_not');
        var punkt_score = (l_count + 1) * 3 + " / " + 3 * last_sol;

        // Meldungen
        var success_meldung = "richtig!";
        var fehler_meldung = "falsch!";
        var melde_mich = document.getElementById('melder');
        // String Formatierung
        var loe_strip = document.getElementById(e_dies).value.replace(/ /g,'');
        var loe_fin = loe_strip.toLowerCase();
        var array_fin = LoesungArray[l_count].toLowerCase();
                // Testen
        if (loe_fin == array_fin){
            melde_mich.innerHTML = success_meldung;
             $('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').fadeIn('2000');
             $('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').focus();

             l_count++;
             score_not.innerHTML = punkt_score;
                $('#score_not').css('display', 'none');
                $('#score_not').fadeTo('3000', 1);
                    // Bei letztem Durchgang
                    if(l_count == last_sol){
                            melde_mich.innerHTML = 'Richtig, du hast alles gelöst!';
                        return false;
                    };
            // Bei Leereingabe
            } else if(document.getElementById(e_dies).value == "") {
            melde_mich.innerHTML = '';
        }
            else {
            melde_mich.innerHTML = fehler_meldung;
                };

    } else {return false};
};
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('halter')` returns a collection. It seems you want to add the event to each element in there but your code right now tries to add it to the collection.

Comment: You're not calling the function `checkLoesung`, you're defining it.

Comment: What do you want to do ? Because you can use the `onsubmit` event to catch when enter is pressed on every input of your form.

Comment: I want to use the ENTER trigger for every input field with the class="halter" . In the final version there will be 10 input fields with this class and each of them should have the same behavior. 
@Arg0n  my bad. should have been a call ... just checkLoesung(id);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declare the function `checkLoesung` outside the if.

also add `[0]` index to `document.getElementsByClassName` because it returns a collection

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('halter')[0].onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){
        
        console.log("Enter");
      return false;
    }
  }
  function checkLoesung(id){//do stuff
        }
```

```html
<input class="halter"  type="text" onkeyup="checkLoesung(id);">
```

> Update based on comment and updated question.

I added the functionality to all `input`s. So, for that, use `document.querySelectorAll` and use a css query. It returns an array. Use `forEach` and add the `addEventListener` for `keypress` to the elements.

> Read the 2 comments I made and Do Whatever you want there.

The code is below.

```js
var l_count = 0; 
var last_sol = 7;  

document.querySelectorAll('.halter').forEach(function(elem){
elem.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){
        //Key pressed is enter. Do whatever you want
        //console.log("Enter");
         alert('hello');
      return false;
    }
    //If required, add an else and add whatever you want when the key pressed is not enter
  });});


function checkLoesung(id){
    if(l_count != last_sol) {

        var e_dies = document.getElementById(id).id;

        var LoesungArray = [
            "Hallo",
            "gesicht",
            "brust",
            "wasser",
            "flasche",
            "tisch",
            "lied"
            ];

        var score_not = document.getElementById('score_not');
        var punkt_score = (l_count + 1) * 3 + " / " + 3 * last_sol;

    
        var success_meldung = "richtig!";
        var fehler_meldung = "falsch!";
        var melde_mich = document.getElementById('melder');
       
        var loe_strip = document.getElementById(e_dies).value.replace(/ /g,'');
        var loe_fin = loe_strip.toLowerCase();
        var array_fin = LoesungArray[l_count].toLowerCase();
               
        if (loe_fin == array_fin){
            melde_mich.innerHTML = success_meldung;
             $('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').fadeIn('2000');
             $('#' + e_dies).nextAll('.halter:first').focus();

             l_count++;
             score_not.innerHTML = punkt_score;
                $('#score_not').css('display', 'none');
                $('#score_not').fadeTo('3000', 1);
                   
                    if(l_count == last_sol){
                            melde_mich.innerHTML = 'Richtig, du hast alles gelöst!';
                        return false;
                    };
            
            } else if(document.getElementById(e_dies).value == "") {
            melde_mich.innerHTML = '';
        }
            else {
            melde_mich.innerHTML = fehler_meldung;
                };

    } else {return false};
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="digger_cont">
<p id="ueberschrift_koth">King of the Hill</p>
<div id="fragen_halter">
<input id="ha_1" class="halter" placeholder="안녕하세요"  type="text" ><br/>
<input id="ha_2" class="halter" placeholder="얼굴" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_3" class="halter" placeholder="유방" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_4" class="halter" placeholder="물" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_5" class="halter" placeholder="병" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_6" class="halter" placeholder="책상" type="text" ><br/><br/>
<input id="ha_7" class="halter" placeholder="노래" type="text" >
</div>
<div id="score_halter">
<p>Punkte: <span id="score_not" style="display:none"></span></p>
<p id="melder"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like I was to slow in typing my answer, anyway here is the jsfiddle in case it helps: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62v7zeqr/)

Comment: I added the `[0]`but it still doesn't work for me. My function is declared after the the snippet you posted. I need to pass the `id` which is missing in the jsfiddle. Might this cause the problem?

Comment: Added the code, thanks! Lots of german comments and variable names tho, sorry about that.

Comment: I copied the code and tried to use `alert('hi');` after `if (keyCode == '13'){` . It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Edit: I mispasted, tried again and the alert works. But still having problems calling the function `checkLoesung(id);` .

Comment: Check the snippet. It is working. You have to add code before `return` statement

Comment: What value you are passing as `id`

Comment: I used to pass `<input class="halter"  type="text" onkeyup="checkLoesung(id);">` the id within the html element. If I run the function with onkeyup in the html element, the whole script works somehow.

Comment: `id` undefined. Instead use `this.id` since the element didn't have an id. It will also be undefined. What value you expecting to be received by the function

Comment: youre a beast, it works!! Any idea why I need to use `this` if I dont include the onkeyup in the html element?

Comment: `this` represent the current object.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing to the element with `getElementsByClassName` it will return an **array**. So you should access to it by using it's index

Here you can test it in this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AI5COL4r1GlviOnJUD8E?p=preview)